# DNSCrypt stopped working on UBUNTU 14.04

Tags: dnscrypt-proxy

I was using DNSCrypt Proxy on my UBUNTU 14.04 for more than a month. Everything was working fine but for over a week the proxy is just not working . 
However when I remove the proxy and use default settings,  internet works again .
Due to restrictions imposed by the college I cant access torrent websites until I use some proxy. I trusted DNSCrypt and It worked for me for over a month and now i just don't know why it doesn't work.
These are my default settings 
[image: http://s22.postimg.org/nxebwwh5d/default.png]

and these are the settings I use to start proxy

[image: http://s1.postimg.org/m2a9pnra7/after.png]

These settings worked very well for me but now i Can't figure out what went wrong.
I need some help urgently in this regard.

Comment: I had set up DNSCrypt on my laptop by following each step provided in the link and used the same settings as recommended
in the guide
http://www.webupd8.org/2014/08/encrypt-dns-traffic-in-ubuntu-with.html

Answer (score 0):

May be you should use the packages from my PPA :

https://launchpad.net/~anton+/+archive/ubuntu/dnscrypt[enter link description here](https://launchpad.net/~anton+/+archive/ubuntu/dnscrypt)

Explanations on how to use it are in more recent webupd8 article :

[Encrypt DNS Traffic In Ubuntu With DNSCrypt [Ubuntu PPA]](https://launchpad.net/~anton+/+archive/ubuntu/dnscrypt)